# Who is "the set of weakly differentiable functions"?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

My question is pretty straightfoward: I would like to be able to think of "the set of weakly differentiable functions". Recall that:

- a function $f:I=(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *weakly differentiable*, with derivative $f'$, if for every $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(I)$ it holds that $ \int_I f'\varphi dx = - \int_I f \varphi' dx $

This seems to imply that $f \in L^1_{loc}([a,b])$. However, a priori, it doesn't explicitly say something about the class of the derivative: is $f'\in L^1, L^2, L^\infty$..?

Is it correct to classify the set of weakly differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ as $W^{1,1}([a,b])$ (or maybe better $W^{1,1}_{loc}([a,b])$)?

If not, is there a notation for such a set?

Comment: I have always thought of Sobolev spaces as spaces of weakly differentiable functions, so your suggestion would be appropriate. I haven't seen them called this explicitly however, and I haven't seen any other sort of notation for such a space.

Comment: @LSK21 Ok, thanks. So, of course all functions in $W^{1,1}_{loc}([a,b])$ are weakly differentiable, by definition. My question is: are we missing any?

Comment: I don't think so. The way I was introduced to weak differentiability was that $f \in L^1_{loc}$ is weakly differentiable if there exists some $g \in L^1_{loc}$ such that for all test functions $\phi$ we have $\int g \phi dx = -\int f \phi' dx$. This would mean that $W^{1,1}$ includes precisely all these functions.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much!